# Op amp voltage signal amplifier

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier

I need help with sensor signal amplification. I have one old industrial unit, which bi-directional signal channel input serves old dual row rheostat type length sensor (about 40 years old application).

Rheostat sensor has spring return, default location in the middle of the scale. Turning the rheostat from the middle into the one direction, it outputs linear voltage between 5.5V to 7.5V to the first input and turning the rheostat from the middle to the opposite side , it outputs linear voltage between 5.5V to 7.5V to the second input. Rheostat supply voltage is +8 volts.
[image]

I have an idea to replace old dual rheostat with modern 5V hall rotary sensor, default mid point 2.5V, "positive movement" signal from 2.5V...4.5V and "negative movement" signal from 2.5V...0,5V. I tried build voltage divider using dual op amp, but it seems to be not working. What i do missing?

Help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I suspect the signal to the other side of the link isn't the *voltage* but the *resistance*, and the changing voltage is only a side effect of the changing resistance.

Comment: Device is already so old, nowhere to find technical library, but in specs was remark that inputs works with signals from 5.5V to 7.5 volts.

Comment: Is there's any pictures of this rheostat device? Probably have zero value for the question, it's just that I like vintage electrical devices.

Comment: In the original circuit with errors, ,the opamp at the top has POSITIVE feedback instead of negative feedback and Will Not Work.

Answer (score 0):

This needs more components than I initially thought. The circuit has to separate sensor voltages above mid point and below midpoint. These voltages must be amplified in different OpAmps.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnc2He.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The input stage with the two diodes and two BJTs separates the sensor deviations from mid point. R17 and R18 provide a "reference" of 2.5 V, Q1 is only conducting if the sensor voltage is above this value, Q2 is only conducting on voltages below that.

So the voltage across R9 will be amplified by OA3. Feedback (R5, R10) and output voltage divider (R6, R8) are calculated to create the desired voltage range of 5.5 V to 7.5 V

The voltage across R12 is amplified by OA6. The resistor network is different because one amplifier is inverting, the other isn't.

The correct function of the circuit depends on a stable 8.0 V supply.

It may be necessary to buffer the outputs with rail to rail voltage follower OpAmps, because a connected load resistance will change the signal voltages.

Comment: Thanks for the notification about outputs load, obviously additional rail-to-rail op amps will be necessary. I did measure original rheostat current between device inputs. If signal level is less than 5.5V, no current flow, 0 mAps, if signal exceeds 5.5V, then load is ca 50mA and increasing to 80mA until rheostat movement end, when voltage is max (7.5V). Device works sometimes with cold weather, when outdoor temperatures may are below 0*C. Probably more temp stabile op amps, than LM324 may are smart option ? Can you add also additional rail-2-rail op amps to the diagram ? Thanks in advance.